# Compare two arrays and extract value that does not match

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays here, I would like to compare both array and extract out the values that does not match. The '3' stands for module credit and 'nfu3ai' stands for module code so both of them comes together, which basically means 'nfu3ai' has credit of '3' and 'sjfru1' has credit of '6'. So the problem with my code now is when I compare the two arrays I only get ['nfu3ai'] and not 3 since 'sgvnfs' has a credit of '3' as well so it gets remove.

```
['6', 'sjfru1', '3', 'nfu3ai', '3', 'sgvnfs']
['3', 'sgvnfs', '6', 'sjfru1']
```

This is my code:

```
      const set1 = new Set(moduleAndCreditByUser); 
      const set2 = new Set(moduleToUpdate);
      const newModule = [ 
                        ...moduleAndCreditByUser.filter(item => 
                        !set2.has(item)),
                        ...moduleToUpdate.filter(item =>        
                        !set1.has(item))];
```

Results:
`['nfu3ai']`

I want to get:
`['3', 'nfu3ai']`

Comment: First you should change your Headline "Compare two error and..." i think you mean "Compare two arrays and..."

Comment: Please provide more information about how and what module credit and code is.

Comment: It sounds like the values at index 0, 2, 4 etc. have a different meaning compared to the values at indexes 1, 3, 5 etc. In my opinion, you should apply this knowledge to your code. Instead of keeping everything bunched together in arrays (or in sets, which even filter things out), the first step should be to pull apart the source arrays into **meaningful objects** or at least into **separate arrays of 'credit'-values and 'code'-values**. And then build a sensible algorithm around that.

Comment: From what I get from the OP's description there should be no match at all since the OP operates on tuples of array data which is like comparing the nested array items of ... `[['6', 'sjfru1'], ['3', 'nfu3ai'], ['3', 'sgvnfs']]` ... to the ones of ... `[['3', 'ST1501'], ['6', 'ST0007']]`. Maybe the OP explains by which value(s) each array item is going to be compared. In addition the OP should provide the expected result in its entirety.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the result ['3', 'nfu3ai'], you need to modify the code to take into account the relationship between module credits and module codes. Here's one way to do it

```
const moduleAndCreditByUser = ['6', 'sjfru1', '3', 'nfu3ai', '3', 'sgvnfs'];
const moduleToUpdate = ['3', 'ST1501', '6', 'ST0007'];

const newModule = [];

for (let i = 0; i < moduleAndCreditByUser.length; i += 2) {
  const credit = moduleAndCreditByUser[i];
  const code = moduleAndCreditByUser[i + 1];

  if (!moduleToUpdate.includes(credit) || !moduleToUpdate.includes(code)) {
    newModule.push(credit, code);
  }
}

console.log(newModule);
```

I hope that it could help.

Comment: @poljs ... Quoting the OP ... _"I want to get: `['3', 'nfu3ai']`"_ ... the OP might either check the result of the above implementation which is ... `['6', 'sjfru1', '3', 'nfu3ai', '3', 'sgvnfs']` ... (and what one would expect) or the OP should consider editing the original Q. accordingly.

Comment: sorry, I have edited my question, just some typo

Answer (score 1):

I can't get it, you have an array with six and four values in it. Where is the declared that " '3' stands for module credit and 'nfu3ai' stands for module code"

The array shows only six values `['6', 'sjfru1', '3', 'nfu3ai', '3', 'sgvnfs']`, but none of them are together. Maybe you should write it in a multiple Array like

```
[['6', 'sjfru1'], [ '3', 'nfu3ai'], ['3', 'sgvnfs']]
```

Is that what you want?

To compare your array you could create a function

```js
function compareArrays(array1, array2) {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return 'Arrays are of different lengths';
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
    if (array1[i] !== array2[i]) {
      return `Values are different at index ${i}. (${array1[i]} vs ${array2[i]})`;
    }
  }
  return 'Arrays have the same values';
}

const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(compareArrays(array1, array2)); // "Arrays have the same values"

const array3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array4 = [4, 3, 2, 1];
console.log(compareArrays(array3, array4)); // "Values are different at index 0 (1 vs 4)"
```